# Error Running Contributions Summary Report

Tags: civireport

When trying to run the Contributions Summary report I get the following message:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2010401) at position 6 (1): Unexpected character
```

Tried standards tricks, checking file permissions, clearing caches unable to resolve the issue.

```
$Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] =&gt; DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2010401) at position 6 (1): Unexpected character
    [code] =&gt; 
    [exception] =&gt; Exception Object
        (
            [message:protected] =&gt; DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2010401) at position 6 (1): Unexpected character
            [string:Exception:private] =&gt; 
            [code:protected] =&gt; 0
            [file:protected] =&gt; /var/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/Summary.php
            [line:protected] =&gt; 745
            [trace:Exception:private] =&gt; Array
```

Comment: Can you check the data format you are using in CiviCRM and the data of the contribution that is the problem (if you can find it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have some invalid data in your database.  I don't think this is related to file permissions or caches.  Is it possible that you imported data via a SQL command rather than the UI or API?

Try turning on the backtrace function in **Administer menu > CiviCRM > Debugging and Error Handling**, and hopefully you'll get a better sense of which field this is supposed to be.  Alternatively, look at the fields that are likely to be called in your instance of the report - checking columns, filters, etc. - and then run SQL commands to find a datetime field with a value of "201401".

Since this is likely to be in civicrm_contribution, I looked up the datetime fields in that table.  There are four.  Try running these commands, then see how this data get entered?

```
SELECT id, contact_id, receive_date FROM civicrm_contribution WHERE receive_date = '201401';
SELECT id, contact_id, receipt_date FROM civicrm_contribution WHERE receipt_date = '201401';
SELECT id, contact_id, cancel_date FROM civicrm_contribution WHERE cancel_date = '201401';
SELECT id, contact_id, thankyou_date FROM civicrm_contribution WHERE thankyou_date = '201401';
```

UPDATE: That backtrace is super-helpful!  I looked at the code in `CRM/Form/Contribute/Summary.php` and I see better what's happening here. The issue is still invalid data - just not in the format I expected.

This part of the code is the part that creates the links on the Summary Report to drill-down links.  See the links in the screenshot:
[image]

So Civi is converting the start dates of each of those months into a different format.  One of your contributions still seems to be happening in a different month.

- You can try commenting out lines 737-786 of the file I mentioned - you'll lose the drill-down links, but hopefully the invalid data doesn't affect anything else.
- This bug shouldn't trigger unless you're grouping by receive date.
- You can try tracking down that bad data.  Try this SQL:

  SELECT id, contact_id, receive_date FROM civicrm_contribution ORDER BY receive_date;
  SELECT id, contact_id, receive_date FROM civicrm_contribution ORDER BY receive_date DESC;

Check the bottom of both those lists for odd-looking receive_dates, my guess is you'll find one!

Comment: Hi Jon, big thanks for your advice. Data has been moved from a debian 6 server and moved to a debian 7 server, so I did use mysqldump to take over data but this was a carbon copy. Database was then upgrade from 4.4 -> 4.5 -> 4.6.
I have checked the contributions table, the only times present are for receive_date and its formatted as "2000-06-08 00:00:00", Can't see any data equalling '2010401'.
Paste binned the main backtrace here; http://pastebin.com/ZuE0zyGf 
Summary.php line 475: $endDate = new DateTime($dateStart);

Comment: I just updated my answer - the backtrace was very helpful!

Comment: Jon, you're a damn genius. I ran the SQL commands and sure enough I found some very odd date formats that weren't consistent with the rest of the data. Thanks again for your help.